# Issue in the return type, i am using typeorm module to export data

Tags: node.js, orm, nestjs

**This is the function and the return type is not being matched**

```
get postgresConfig(): TypeOrmModuleOptions { let entities = [ __dirname + '/../../modules//.entity{.ts,.js}', __dirname + '/../../modules/**/.view-entity{.ts,.js}', ]; let migrations = [__dirname + '/../../database/migrations/*    {.ts,.js}'];
if (module.hot) {
  const entityContext = require.context(
    './../../modules',
    true,
    /\.entity\.ts$/,
  );
  entities = entityContext.keys().map((id) => {
    const entityModule = entityContext<Record<string, unknown>>(id);
    const [entity] = Object.values(entityModule);

    return entity as string;
  });
  const migrationContext = require.context(
    './../../database/migrations',
    false,
    /\.ts$/,
  );

  migrations = migrationContext.keys().map((id) => {
    const migrationModule = migrationContext<Record<string, unknown>>(id);
    const [migration] = Object.values(migrationModule);

    return migration as string;
  });
}

const databaseConfig = {
  entities,
  migrations,
  keepConnectionAlive: !this.isTest,
  dropSchema: this.isTest,
  type: this.getString('DB_TYPE'), // postgres | mysql | mongodb
  name: 'default',
  subscribers: [UserSubscriber],
  migrationsRun: true,
  logging: this.getBoolean('ENABLE_ORM_LOGS'),
  namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
  replication:{}
};

if (this.getBoolean('DB_MASTER_SLAVE')) {
  databaseConfig.replication = {
    master: {
      host: this.getString('DB_HOST'),
      port: this.getNumber('DB_PORT'),
      username: this.getString('DB_USERNAME'),
      password: this.getString('DB_PASSWORD'),
      database: this.getString('DB_DATABASE'),
    },
    slaves: [
      {
        host: this.getString('DB_SLAVE_HOST'),
        port: this.getNumber('DB_SLAVE_PORT'),
        username: this.getString('DB_SLAVE_USERNAME'),
        password: this.getString('DB_SLAVE_PASSWORD'),
        database: this.getString('DB_SLAVE_DATABASE'),
      },
    ],
  };
}

return databaseConfig; // **ERROR ON THIS LINE OF MISMATCHED TYPE**
```

}

**The interface is defined as follows**

`import { Connection, ConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm';`

`export declare type TypeOrmModuleOptions = {`

`retryAttempts?: number;    retryDelay?: number; toRetry?: (err: any) => boolean; autoLoadEntities?: boolean;  keepConnectionAlive?: boolean; verboseRetryLog?: boolean;`

`} & Partial<ConnectionOptions>;`

**The database config is used as follows:**

```
    `TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          imports: [SharedModule],
          useFactory: (configService: ApiConfigService) =>
            configService.postgresConfig,
          inject: [ApiConfigService],
        }),
```

**upon starting the nestjs application i am getting error**
`
Type '{ entities: string[]; migrations: string[]; keepConnectionAlive: boolean; dropSchema: boolean; type: string; name: string; subscribers: (typeof UserSubscriber)[]; migrationsRun: boolean; logging: boolean; namingStrategy: SnakeNamingStrategy; replication: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'TypeOrmModuleOptions'.
Type '{ entities: string[]; migrations: string[]; keepConnectionAlive: boolean; dropSchema: boolean; type: string; name: string; subscribers: (typeof UserSubscriber)[]; migrationsRun: boolean; logging: boolean; namingStrategy: SnakeNamingStrategy; replication: {}; }' is not assignable to type '{ retryAttempts?: number | undefined; retryDelay?: number | undefined; toRetry?: ((err: any) => boolean) | undefined; autoLoadEntities?: boolean | undefined; keepConnectionAlive?: boolean | undefined; verboseRetryLog?: boolean | undefined; } & Partial<...>'.
Type '{ entities: string[]; migrations: string[]; keepConnectionAlive: boolean; dropSchema: boolean; type: string; name: string; subscribers: (typeof UserSubscriber)[]; migrationsRun: boolean; logging: boolean; namingStrategy: SnakeNamingStrategy; replication: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<OracleConnectionOptions>'.
Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"oracle" | undefined'.

```
128     return databaseConfig;
`
```